# Open Search Server: Ignore content but follow links

Tags: search-engine, opensearch

I have OSS set up for searches on a community site. The basic set up works fine but now I need to fine tune it. An important part of that is making sure the indexing saves the right parts from every page but ignores parts that are common for all pages (ie the footer), however those parts are neccessary for the crawler for finding all parts of the site via the links. I'm aware of the [`opensearchserver.ignore` class](http://www.open-search-server.com/confluence/display/EN/Exclude+certain+part+of+webpage+from+crawling):

```
<div class="opensearchserver.ignore">
    This text should not be indexed.
</div>
```

But since the links are important, a tag like this would come in handy:

```
<div class='noindexbutfollow'> 
    This will not be indexed but the link {Open Search Server} would be followed 
</div>
```

(As discussed in [this thread](https://sourceforge.net/p/opensearchserve/discussion/947148/thread/877e8ea0).)

Is this possible?